# Where is the single-crossing point between a distribution and its single mean-preserving spread?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable

Consider two random variables, $Z_A$ and $Z_B$, with the same expected value $\mu$, having distribution functions $F_A$ and $F_B$, respectively. Let $Z_B$ be obtained by a **single** mean-preserving spread of $Z_A$. This implies that $F_A(z)$ and $F_B(z)$ are single-crossing: there is an unique $\tilde{z}$ on the support such that $F_A(\tilde{z})=F_B(\tilde{z})$. Moreover, $F_A(\tilde{z})<F_B(\tilde{z})$ for $z<\tilde{z}$ and $F_A(\tilde{z})>F_B(\tilde{z})$ for $z>\tilde{z}$.

My question is: do we in general know where this single-crossing point lies for this "simple" single mean-preserving spread case (perhaps in relationhsip with the expected value $\mu$, or some other moment)?

Comment: Did the author ever find an answer? If so, please update us! I have this question too. :)

Comment: Sorry, but I never found a definite answer. I settled for the following: the exact position of the threshold $\tilde{z}$ depends on the particular distribution. For example, for some commonly used income and wealth distributions subject to a single mean-preserving spread, like shifted Pareto and Lognormal, the single-crossing point is not smaller than the mean, and the distance between crossing point and mean is weakly increasing in the mean-preserving spread. Cannot find a source right now though, but can be proven

Comment: You should put your answer as an official answer and I will upvote it, as I otherwise have no leads on this. I'll also add: For a symmetric distribution, I think the intersection is the mean/median.